# How to get side column table data to sort entity bound tables?

Tags: c#, asp.net, listview, webforms, entity

I'm working on scheduling project. I am using entity codefirst approach for the schedule data (string schedule day, int schedule number 1 for morning 2 for noon and 3 for evening).

My question is, how do I display this information as the following:

```
Shiftnum--sunday--monday--tuesday--wedn-
--  1   -- user1--      --     --user2
--  2   --      --user2 --     --
--  3   --      --      --user1--
```

Using webforms with either gridview or listview?

Comment: populate your data into a DataTable for your GridView to display

Comment: thing is i kind of have to use entity framework for this project, do i have to use data set to use DataTable?